# How to handle async callback promise rejection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Try to handle every exception in my async code (nodeJS, ExpressJS):
Here is almost pseudo code. I use limiter (npm limiter)  module with method removeTokens (num, callback(err,remainingRequest)). Big part of code is inside the callback, and I wanna catch and throw any error there to the handler, but for now the error inside callback is still marked as "unhandled exception" and I don't understand why.

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    ...
    return getAll();

    async function getAll () {
      limiter.removeTokens(1, async (err, remainingRequest) => {
        try {
          throw new Error('THROWN')
        } catch (error) {
          throw error
        }
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't pass `async` functions into things that don't expect them (unless you catch all errors, as you are with your `app.post` callback). Instead, give yourself a wrapper for `limiter.removeTokens` that returns a promise:

```
function removeTokens(limiter, id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        limiter.removeTokens(id, (err, remainingRequest) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(remainingRequest);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

(You might also look into [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) for that.)

Then:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    ...
    await getAll(); // *** Or you might just use `removeTokens(limiter, 1)` directly here

    function getAll() {
      return removeTokens(limiter, 1);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Here it is using `removeTokens` directly:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    ...
    await removeTokens(limiter, 1);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if possible please share as much code as you can as then it is easy for us to debug where the problem might be.
Coming you your question i think the problem is that in your `try..catch` block you are throwing the error instead of handling it with a `reject`. Below i have pasted a code block which you can try and let me know if it works for you. Please not the syntax might be different but the idea is that you have to `reject` the Promise in case of error.

````````````````
`````````limiter.removeTokens(1, async (err, remainingRequest) => {
````````````try {
```````````````throw new Error('THROWN')
````````````} catch (error) {
```````````````return Promise.reject(error) //
````````````}
`````````})
``````}
```} catch (error) {
``````console.log(error);
```}
})
````````````````